# Sorting multidimensional array by two user defined values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a multidimensional array by two values.

For example in the array will be 4 keys.

```
Array(
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => downloading
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 60
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => downloading
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 30
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => paused
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 30
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => completed
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 100
    )
)
```

Is there a way I can sort the array so that it would sort the arrays with key completed first, then downloading second, then paused third and then also sort the arrays containing downloading and paused from 100 down to 0 by the `3` key?

Desired output would be

```
Array(
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => completed
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 100
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => downloading
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 60
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => downloading
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 30
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42
        [1] => paused
        [2] => Title
        [3] => 30
    )
)
```

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I know how to sort basic arrays but I wouldn't know where to start on a more complex array like this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $array = [
        [
            '4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42',
            'downloading',
            'Title',
            '60',
        ],
        [
            '4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42',
            'downloading',
            'Title',
            '30',
        ],
        [
            '4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42',
            'paused',
            'Title',
            '30',
        ],
        [
            '4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42',
            'completed',
            'Title',
            '100',
        ]
    ];


    usort($array, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
            if ($a[3] == $b[3]) {
                return 0;
            }

            return ($a[3] > $b[3]) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        $status = ['completed', 'downloading', 'paused'];

        foreach ($status as $st) {
            if ($a[1] == $st)
                return -1;
            if ($b[1] == $st)
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    });


    var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

[uksort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uksort.php) is what you need.

It is a sort that lets you define you own callback function.

This callback function is then used by uksort to reorder the array.

You need to write a function that will sort an array based on two criterias.

The first one is the alphabetical order of the field at indice 1 of your array (which contains the words completed, downloading, ...) and in case of tie you would then use the field at indice 3 of your array and sort in decreasing order.

Finally, you will need to pass the function you created as a parameter to uksort.

Hope it helps ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reformat your array and use array_multisort. It will also make thinks more readable:

```
<?php $ar = Array(
    Array(
        "id" => "4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42",
        "status" => "completed",
        "title" => "Title",
        "rank" => "100",
    ),
    Array
    (
        "id" => "4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42",
        "status" => "downloading",
        "title" => "Title",
        "rank" => "60",
    ),
    Array
    (
        "id" => "4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42",
        "status" => "downloading",
        "title" => "Title",
        "rank" => "30",
    ),
    Array
    (
        "id" => "4B642D022980E5EBAA7CF4B6E1CC93769921CB42",
        "status" => "paused",
        "title" => "Title",
        "rank" => "30",
    ),
);
var_dump($ar);
foreach ($ar as $key => $row) {
    $status[$key] = $row['status'];
    $rank[$key] = $row['rank'];
}

array_multisort($status, SORT_ASC, $rank, SORT_DESC, $ar);
var_dump($ar);
```